# Help regarding an exercise in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f, g$ be entire functions and $ |f(z)| \le (1+|z|) |g(z)|$ for every $z \in \Bbb C$. Prove that there exist $λ, μ \in \Bbb C$ with $|λ|,|μ| \le 1$ so that $f(z)=(λz + μ)g(z)$.

If $ g(a)=0 $ for $a \in \Bbb C$, it says that $a$ is a removable singularity for $\frac fg$

Why is that? Is it because when $z$ approaches $a, \frac fg$ does not become infinite?

Comment: What is "it" that you refer to?  On this site, we look for more than just a statement of a question - we also look for background and context. This helps make the problem more meaningful, and helps others find it in the future. You can edit the post to add additional information.

Comment: It refers to the professor solving it. He argues that the singularity is removable so that he can expand $\frac fg$ into an entire function and use Liouville's theorem. It wasn't explained and I got stuck

Comment: If you like I can write the whole exercise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the point $a$ is a removable singularity of $f/g$ suffices to prove that

$$\lim_{z\to a}(z-a) \dfrac{f}{g}(z) = 0.$$

In other words, given $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that if $|z-a|<\delta$ then

$$\left|(z-a)\dfrac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right| < \epsilon.$$

**Constructing $\delta$**

$$\left|(z-a)\dfrac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right| = |z-a|\left|\dfrac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right|\leq|z-a|(1+|z|),$$

because of the hypothesis over $f$ and $g$. Now, suppose $|z-a|<1$, then we have

$$|z|=|z-a+a|\leq |z-a|+|a|< 1+|a|,$$

so that if $|z-a|<1$ we have

$$\left|(z-a)\dfrac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right| \leq |z-a|(1+|z|)<|z-a|(2+|a|),$$

since we can bound $|z-a|$ at will, the proof will be as follows.

**Proof of the limit**

Given $\epsilon > 0$ let

$$\delta = \min\left\{1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{2+|a|}\right\},$$

in that case if $|z-a|<\delta$ then we have in particular $|z-a|<1$, so that as we already saw $|z|<1+|a|$, in that case

$$\left|(z-a)\dfrac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right| \leq |z-a|(1+|z|) < |z-a|(2+|a|)$$

but since $|z-a|<\delta$ it follows that $|z-a|<\epsilon/(2+|a|)$ and hence

$$\left|(z-a)\dfrac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2+|a|}(2+|a|) = \epsilon$$

which proves the limit and proves $a$ is a removable singularity.

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality implies that $f/g$ is locally bounded. So indeed any singularity (except maybe the one at infinity) is removable.

Concerning the second part of your question:

> **Claim** If $|h(z)|\le 1 + |z|$, then $h(z) = \lambda z + \mu$ with $|\lambda|<1$, $|\mu|<1$.

*Proof* Define $k(z) = h(z) - h(0)$. Then it is easy to see that $|k(z)| \le 2+|z|$. Then the function $k(z)/z$ is bounded. Indeed, it is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$ since $k(0) = 0$, and $\limsup_{|z|\to \infty} |k(z)|/|z| \le 1$. Then by Liouville's theorem, $k(z)/z = \lambda$ must be constant, moreover, $|\lambda| \le 1$ by the last inequality. It remains to note that $|h(0)|\le 1$ by the assumption.